# Knockout dynamic <select> options override select value

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

The issue i am having is related to dynamic select options with AJAX.

The use case is that changing the value in select #1 should populate the options in select #2 through ajax. What it is uncommon is that the value of select #2 also comes asynchronously, but with different ajax.

The [jsFiffle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkf4L860/5/) shows the following code (simplified - only 1 ajaxlike timeout). We have 2 selects, one with static options, other with dynamic options. Both have value binding.

```
<select id="select_1" data-bind="value: select_1_value">
<option selected>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<select id="select_2" data-bind="options:selectOptions, value: select_2_value"></select>
Select 2 value is <span data-bind="text: select_2_value">
```

Js part looks like this:

```
var vm = function AppViewModel() {
this.selectOptions = ko.observableArray(['a','b','c']);
this.select_1_value = ko.observable(1);
this.select_2_value = ko.observable('a');

this.computedValue = ko.computed( function () {
    <!-- prevent from initial -->
    if (this.select_1_value() != 1)
    {
    console.log('changed');
    this.select_1_value();

    this.selectOptions.removeAll()
    var self = this
    setTimeout(function(){
       self.selectOptions.push(['e']);
       self.selectOptions.push(['f']);
       <!-- DOES WORK But i do not want it here -->
       <!--self.select_2_value('f');  -->
    }, 1000);        
    <!-- DOES NOT WORK -->
    this.select_2_value('f');
    }
}, this);   
}

$(function() {
   ko.applyBindings(new vm());
});
```

What you can see in the jsfiddle is that when select_2_value is set not in the asynch part it gets overwritten when clearing the options observableArray.

I assume there is a design flaw around. Could you please pin point it out for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use knockout's [valueAllowUnset](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#using-valueallowunset-with-select-elements) binding, which will not clear the value if it isn't present in the select options.

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkf4L860/6/)

```
<select id="select_1" data-bind="value: select_1_value">
    <option selected>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<select id="select_2" data-bind="options:selectOptions, value: select_2_value, valueAllowUnset:true"></select>

Select 2 value is <span data-bind="text: select_2_value">
```